# Why only 2 out 3 JMeter Thread group execute?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I've a JMeter Test Plan with 3 thread groups, but when I run the test plan of these only 2 run at any given time. Any idea why?

Comment: show us how they are configured

Answer (score 0):

**By default, JMeter runs "Thread Groups" concurrently,** unless otherwise we checked the "Run Thread group consequently" in "Test Plan". Below is the screen shot.

[image]

Follow the below Steps :

```
1.Verify "Test Plan", make sure that uncheck "Run Thread group consequently" check box.
2.Use Latest JMeter (not mandatory, but better to have it)
3.Run the JMeter test
```

Comment: I've this unchecked, but still only 2 threadgroup run at any point in time.

Comment: Which version of JMeter you are using

Comment: I failed to mention that all threads loop through a CSV file with equal number of rows and for thread 3 I immediately see "jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread seen: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: End of file detected" as soon as it starts. But other threads continue

Comment: In "CSV Data Set Config", what is the value for  "Stop thread on EOF" ?

Comment: Stop on EOF is true as I do want to thread to stop and only process the values that are there. So if I've 10 values, i want to end after 10 and each threadgroup has a separate CSV config.

Comment: The reason for third Thread group is not starting is "CSV Data Set Config" reached end of the file. Means all entries are used by First and Second Thread Groups and there is no value in that file to run Third thread Group. To make you script run , you have to do one of the two approaches

Comment: I've different CSV config for each thread group still it does not execute

Comment: check for errors in jmeter.log file and let me know

Comment: actually its working now, I'd to select "Start Next Thread Loop" on sampler error for each threadgroup